# Zendesk SDK vs. API

Tags: android, ios, api, sdk, zendesk

Has anyone used the Zendesk SDK?

I'm thinking about using it because it provides a lot of functionality out-of-the-box. But is it unsecure or error prone?

In which case, would you recommend just using the Zendesk API instead?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK itself uses the Zendesk API (over https always) to get the data it needs. You can read about how secure authentication is performed in the [authentication docs](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios/authentication).

A list of known issues is also maintained in [the documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios/knownissues) by the dedicated Mobile SDK team at Zendesk.